# Can not ping device names only IP address

Tags: networking, wireless-router, ping, wireless-access-point

I have two routers at home when on one router I can ping LAN machines via their names, but when on the other router the relevant LAN computers or devices can not be ping via their names, but IP ping works.

So what is it that makes us ping computer names instead of IPs ?

It is simple WIFI routers with clients connected to wifi, no special domains etc.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Generally what controls the machine name resolution is the DNS server, which in this case is probably going to be the router connected directly to your modem (unless your modem is a modem/router combo).

The DNS is what finds the ip for the computer names, but the second router is probably trying to act as the DNS as well.  So think of it this way, Router 1 can find all machine addresses because all computers go through it for the network/internet, but Router 2 can only check the computers connecting through it.  I would check the DNS setting on Router 1, and put the same settings into Router 2 (should be the IP for your Router 1 or Modem).

You want to use the same DNS on the entire network, or you run into issues like that where your network is split into different pieces.

I hope that makes sense, if not I'll try to clarify whatever I didn't word correctly.